# Function as a class - create getters and setters for private properties

Tags: javascript, prototype

The way I figured, when creating a new function (that represents a class), it is considered a good practice to define additional functions with the help of the prototype. If functions are declared through `this` within an existing function, they get created for each instance, which we don't necessarily want.

So, my question is - if I want to have a property that is completely private and can be access only through getters and setters, is it even possible to achieve this by using the prototype?

Here's an example:

```
function Item() {
  var title = '';

  this.setTitle = function(_title) {
    title = _title;
  };

  this.getTitle = function() {
    return title;
  };
}

var car = new Item();
car.setTitle('car');

console.log(car.getTitle()); //car
console.log(car.title); // undefined

/*
  Alternative
*/

function _Item() {
  this.title = '';
}

_Item.prototype.setTitle = function(_title){
  this.title = _title;
};

_Item.prototype.getTitle = function() {
  return this.title;
};

var _car = new _Item();
_car.setTitle('car 2');
console.log(_car.getTitle()); // car
console.log(_car.title); // car
```

as can be seen from the example above, in the case of `Item`, I declared getters and setters within a function - not a good practice. But in this way, I managed to keep the `title` property private. However, in case of `_Item`, I'm using the prototype approach, which is preferred, but my `title` property is not private at all.

So, what's the best approach at creating private properties of "classes" in JavaScript?

Comment: No, if you want a private property, which is a variable local to the constructor, then obviously methods which access it must also be defined within the constructor.

Comment: ditto what @torazaburo said - private properties are a _lexical construct_, and by definition a function on the prototype cannot access the same lexical scope as the constructor.

Comment: NB: they're private _variables_, not properties, as such.

Comment: Of course, your `title` isn't very private even the first example, given that you've defined a public getter and setter for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you want a private property, which by definition is a variable local to the constructor, then obviously methods which access it must also be defined within the constructor.

Many people worry about the efficiency implications of defining a method once on a prototype, versus defining it once on every instance. This might have been a valid concern ten years ago, or today in applications that are creating thousands or millions of objects. Otherwise, realistically it's not something you need to worry about.

Comment: The last piece is what was bugging me - the efficiency of implementations. I suppose there's no "right" or "wrong" way, but it depends on the case?